# Qt: XML stream does not write string directly

Tags: xml, qt, qt4, xml-parsing

My problem is the following: my program works with projects and saves their settings in an XML file. It also creates viewable HTML files using the same `QXmlStreamWriter` class. However, because XML is supposed to skip particular symbols, a lot of characters are not propery represented in the HTML file. Is there a way to write any QString directly into an HTML file using an XML stream? Something like `writeRaw()` function?

Because I could not find solution to this problem, I had to create a `QTextStream(xml->device())` and write into the stream. However, the stream seems to work assynchronously and, dpeending on the situation, sometimes it writes its part of code only after XML stream has finished writing the whole file. In HTML terms, it means, that a part of the code appears after `</html>` tag. Is there any other solution?

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved my issue.

In the documentaion it says that `QString::QString(QByteArray&)` converts a byte array to a strong using `QString::fromAscii()` function. I replaced this part with `QString::fromUtf8(myByteArray)`, and it worked!

Comment: note that fromAscii is not exactly what (i guess) you think. If a codec has been set using QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(), it is used to convert str to Unicode; otherwise this function does the same as fromLatin1().